# Exporting MySQL data to an RTF template creating multiple pages

Tags: mysql, loops, header, content-type

The data pulled from the database inserts into an RTF template without a problem as long as I only have 1 row. If I put my `header("Content-type: text/rtf")` inside the loop, however, I receive a headers already sent error. When removing the headers from the code, the raw data prints properly in the browser window.

How do I combine data from multiple records in the database to create multiple documents (or 1 document with page breaks)?

Code here:

```
$document='../docs/letter.rtf';
$qry="Select * from table";
$result=mysql_query($qry);
$num_row=mysql_num_rows($result);

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$account_id=$row['pk_account];
$name=$row['first_name'];
$file_doc='01-'.$pk_account.'.rtf';
....

$body=file_get_contents($document);
$body=str_replace("NAME", $name, $body);
....

for($i=0; $i<$num_rows; $i++){
}

header("Content-type: text/rtf");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment; filename={$file_doc}");
echo $body;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Bryan. That is what I need to do, but can't figure out how to do it. When I build the $body string inside the loop then send header and body, outside, only the last record gets sent to the template.

Comment: You need to append your $body. See code in answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate your $body. So instead of this:

```
$body=file_get_contents($document);
$body=str_replace("NAME", $name, $body);
```

try this:

```
$body.=str_replace("NAME", $name, file_get_contents($document));
```

Then place this outside your while loop:

```
header("Content-type: text/rtf");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment; filename={$file_doc}");
echo $body;
```

Comment: Thank you. You have led me down the right track, but I still can't get it to work. I have many lines of str_replace(Name...) str_replace(city...) str_replace(state...) etc. When I concantenate them all (.=), the output template doesn't populate with the mysql data, it remains unchanged. It also generates only 1 RTF document, although there are 8 records pulled by the while loop. I am working on this day 2. Any other suggestions?

Comment: $file_doc='01-'.$pk_account.'.rtf'; runs every loop and overwrites the file name. This is what's happening in your code with your body and any other data. It just get rewritten every loop. You need to walk through your code execution step by step and clean up the logical flow. Also, you may be trying to accomplish two different things in one loop (generate multiple files and then stream them to the browser).

Comment: I suggest either saving multiple files to the file system and then handling the download separately or combining all the data into one file (which I think you're trying to do now). Either way, the browser always expects only one response (not multiple) per request/execution, to put it simply.